# Como puedo hacer un buscador en tiempo real con js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Estoy tratando de hacer un buscador en tiempo relacionado a dropDownItems en donde vaya escribiendo se vaya filtrando los nombres de los clientes ingresados, estuve viendo que se puede hacer con js pero solo he encontrado ejemplos muy basicos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo del mantenedor que se conecta con la base de datos de mi sistema

```
  @using Model
  @using Model.ViewModels
  @using Sys.PortalVendedor.Models
  @model List<Pedido>
  @{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  var permisos = (PermisoView)ViewData["permisosUsuario"];

  <div class="content-wrapper">

<!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
<section class="content-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h1>Listado de Pedidos</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="@Url.Content("~/Home")">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Pedidos</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="content">

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-12">

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h5 style="text-align:left">Seleccione el Cliente</h5>
                        <div class="input-group mb-1" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                            <div class="row" style="align-items:flex-start">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="buscar" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre del Cliente"/>
                                    <button class="btn btn-info" id="buscarEmpleado" type="button" style="margin-top:1px;margin-left:1px!important">Buscar</button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-warning" id="limpiar" type="button" style="margin-top: 1px; margin-left: 1px!important">Limpiar </button>
                                    
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.DropDownList("idEmpleado_EmpleadoProyecto", ClienteHelper.GetClientes(), "(Seleccione Cliente)", new { @class = "form-control input-md text-uppercase", @required = true, style="margin-left: 1rem" })
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="card-tools">
                                @if (permisos.Crear)
                                {
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Crear", "Pedido", new { })" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-left:50rem;">CrearPedido <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>

                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>



                    </div>

                    <!-- /.card-header -->
                    <div class="card-body">

                        <table id="tbpedidos" class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width:100%;">

                            <thead>

                                <tr>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Numero Pedido</th>
                                    <th>Fecha</th>
                                    <th>Cliente</th>
                                    <th>Forma de Pago</th>
                                    <th>Notas del Pedido</th>
                                    <th>Direccion</th>
                                    <th>Fecha de Entrega</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (var item in Model)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>@item.IdPedido</td>
                                        <td>@item.Numero</td>
                                        <td>@item.Fecha.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</td>
                                        <td class="articulo">@item.Cliente.Nombre</td>
                                        <td>@item.FormaPago.Nombre</td>
                                        <td>@item.NotasPedido</td>
                                        <td>@item.Direccion</td>
                                        <td>@item.FechaEntrega.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") 
 </td>

                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>

                        </table>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>

</div>


}
```

He tratado con algunos ejemplos pero no me hace filtro que necesito hacer para que se aplique en mi vista de html, lo que necesito es que cuando seleccione el cliente sea en la caja de texto o en el drop se muestren los datos en mi tabla

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente no es la respuesta que quieres,pero en vez de hacerlo tú, puedes usar un componente que ya lo haga por ti. En mi caso lo prefiero porque suelen tener mejor aspecto del que soy capaz de darle yo.

Si no he entendido mal, la idea es filtrar los clientes del combo. En mi caso uso este: [Typeahead](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead)

Si la idea fuese filtrar la tabla, en mi caso uso este otro: [DataTables](https://datatables.net) ya que tiene búsqueda, paginación, etc. También tiene un plugin para extender los filtros que ya trae por defecto.